# COUNT DISTINCT PER USER

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table recording date, device names and imei numbers of each device name of each user every time they log in a website like this:

- user_id
- date
- devicename
- imei

I want to get the number of users who have the number of devices >= 2 (use imei number) for the last 30 days and raw data in the format:

```
user_id     date         devicename     imei
abc         2022-03-02   xyz             123
abc         2022-03-03   xyz             456
abc         2022-03-01   tuv             789
def         2022-03-01   poq             102
.......
```

I have already done the code to get the number of users with distinct devices >=2:

```
WITH raw AS(
  SELECT DISTINCT
      user_id
  FROM
    table
  WHERE
    1=1
    AND DATE BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE('+7'), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
    AND CURRENT_DATE('+7')
  GROUP BY
    1
  HAVING
 COUNT(DISTINCT IMEI) >= 2 )
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM raw
```

But I think there may be some mistakes here. Please check and revise the code if needed and propose the solution for the second question.

Thank you for your help. Really appreciate your attention.

Answer (score 0):

lemme know if this worked:

```
select count(user_id)
from (
   select user_id, count(distinct imei) as total
   from `table_name`
   where date_diff(current_date, date, day) <= 30 
   group by 1 
   having total >=2)
```